# Search results are from our test site instead of the live site. Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

When you go to my site https://www.gesusa.com and search for example Maxjax, the items in the result goes to https://test.gesusa.com/

Comment: you get your solution or not>

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using some external system to get your products (like elasticsearch) you may need to reindex.
Also check if your test server does not link to the same external system as your main website.
I see that when I perform a search there is a call to `https://gesupply-ac.celebros.com/AutoCompleteWebServiceV2/GetSuggestions.aspx?....`
And that call returns an xml where the products link to `test.gesusa.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Not just search results, but all of the products in any product listing are linking with your staging server.

Check the list file `PathToYourTheme/catalog/product/list.phtml` your anchor tags (`a`) surely has hard coded links. Please use dynamic products links like `$_product->getProductUrl()`

This should fix the issue